# Double quotes being added when posting form in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multipartform-data

I'm posting to an ASP.NET MVC server using:

```
var request = require("request");
...
var formData = {
                    designerCode: data.designerCode,
                    designCode: data.designCode,
                    designName: data.designName,
                    package: zipBuffer
                }
var url = constants.upload_zip_url + "/job/upload/" + encodeURIComponent(data.jobId) + "/" + encodeURIComponent(data.clientId);
                request.post({
                    url: url,
                    headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + pniGlobalAuthToken},
                    formData: formData
                }, function postCallback(err, response, body) {
                    console.log(err, response, body);
                })
```

On the server I have:

```
using (var requestContent = Request.Content)
        {
            var contents = (await requestContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync()).Contents;
            var contentDic = contents.ToDictionary(c => c.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name);
```

However at this point:

```
contentDic.Keys
Count = 4
[0]: "\"designCode\""
[1]: "\"designName\""
[2]: "\"package\""
[3]: "\"designerCode\""
```

So the request module is adding quotes around the form key values. Is it hard coded, or is there a parameter to turn it off? I looked at the documentation, but can't find anything:https://github.com/request/request

I can always strip the quotes on the server, but this is annoying. Request is the most convenient Node module that I've found. Has anyone else encountered something similar?